# Взаимодействие сервера с клиентом

Tags: android, api, клиент-сервер

У меня есть клиент-серверное приложение, в нем пользователь(Sender) может отсылать задачи другому пользователю(Receiver) с помощью REST API на сервере. И пользователь Receiver может получать задачи только если сделал запрос на сервер о получение своих задач. Как можно создать callback на сервере чтобы сервер уведомлял о пришедших задачах receiver`a?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервер через REST мне кажется не сможет уведомить пользователя о новых задачах. Я бы делал все через фоновый запрос-ответ. Суть такая - вы каждые к примеру 10 секунд шлете запрос на сервер о новых задачах, и если они есть то показываете пользователю уведомление. Это будет проще чем лепить что-то на сервере и не факт что вы получите то что вам нужно. Вот например :

```
class CheckNewMessages : Service() {
    private val mHandler = Handler()
    private var mTimer: Timer? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer!!.cancel()
        } else {
            mTimer = Timer()
        }
        mTimer!!.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        val restartService = Intent("RestartService")
        if (!log_out) {
            sendBroadcast(restartService)
        }

        super.onDestroy()
    }

    internal inner class TimeDisplayTimerTask : TimerTask() {

        override fun run() {

            mHandler.postDelayed({

            }, 100)
        }

    }

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFY_INTERVAL: Long = 1000
        var log_out = false
    }

}
```

и дальше уже в handler при наличии новых задач вы отправляете уведомление. Это будет проще чем делать уведомления через сервер.

Можно конечно подключить Firebase, но это уже чересчур мне кажется :)

Comment: Это не будет сильно тратить зарядку?

Comment: любая фоновая активность приложения тратит заряд аккумулятора, если вы будете делать через сервер или через фоновую задачу вам будет нужен интернет для получения данных с сервера, поэтому да это будет тратить заряд, вопрос насколько сильно - я не знаю с чем сравнивать, но вряд ли очень сильно, так как данных будет не очень много и запрос будет один.